# Wired connection only available when charging

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, battery, wired

Why does my ethernet stop working when I'm on battery power? I'd like to connect full time when I'm utilizing my battery, but I'm unable to. It was working just fine before. This is the output of sudo lshw -C network:

````
[sudo] password for chris: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: 5c:26:0a:4e:5d:f1
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:25 memory:e6e00000-e6e1ffff memory:e6e80000-e6e80fff ioport:5080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 35
       serial: 24:77:03:4b:f0:f4
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-22-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.1.45 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:28 memory:e6d00000-e6d01fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: virbr0
       serial: 52:54:00:53:86:79
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:53:86:79
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s```
````

Comment: Because it draws something like 5 watts power management software will turn it off to save electricity when you are running on battery. This makes sense because if you can plug in ethernet logic dictates a wall outlet is close by to plug in your laptop charger too. Are you using `tlp` if so I think you can override the setting in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that as soon as I get back to the computer

Comment: What setting would I be looking for @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: So you are using `tlp` then?

Comment: I have `tlp` installed, and I have the GUI as well

Comment: OK I'll dig up some notes and post an answer. Give me some time I don't actually use my laptop on battery power, it just sits on a coffee table :)

Comment: Thank you, I really need that

Answer (score 0):

Because the Ethernet LAN Adapter draws electricity, power management software will turn it off to save electricity when you are running on battery. This makes sense because if you can plug in Ethernet logic dictates a wall outlet is close by to plug in your laptop charger too.

I found this general article about [power consumption](https://www.quora.com/Which-drains-more-battery-power-on-a-mac-Wifi-or-ethernet):

> Bluetooth power consumption will range from 2-24 mW depending on the
>   amount of activity; Wi-Fi consumes between 10 mW and 800 mW
>   (transmitting full bandwidth); Wired ethernet consumes 50mW to 1W
>   (full-duplex gigabit ethernet at full load).

Another user encountered a similar problem to you in **Redit**:

- [Can't get ethernet up with TLP in battery mode](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/7jvsvf/cant_get_ethernet_up_with_tlp_in_battery_mode/)

Since you are using `tlp` you can override the setting in your configuration file (`/etc/default/tlp`). What the Redit user did was add:

```
RUNTIME_PM_BLACKLIST="00:1f.6"
```

Of course that is the address of their LAN card and yours will probably be different. Visit the thread for more details on how to obtain your card's address.